# Update SQL Server Table Based on User Level Input

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am reading the contents of a table into my C# application, in which the end user will be able to edit the data. I then wish to send this new information back to the database.

```
DataTable Table = new DataTable("TestTable");
            using (SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string queryStatement = "SELECT * FROM dbo.usr_Table ORDER BY code ASC";

                using (SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStatement, _con))
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter _dap = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd);

                    _con.Open();
                    _dap.Fill(Table);
                    _con.Close();
                }
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = Table;
```

I'm confident enough in SQL to write an UPDATE statement, inline with my C# code, but is this the best/most efficient way to go about it?

I will have to update based on each row in the new application side, could I have something like this?;

```
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE usr_Table SET description= @description, subject = @subject, text = @text, status = @status WHERE code = @code", connectionString);
```

If so, how do I assign the values in the C# table to the variables?

Many thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use StoredProcedure?

Comment: How would I declare the C# table values in a StoredProcedure? Surely the SP would be server-side, no? Or is there a C# equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally use LINQ to do this kind of process, but if you want or need to roll your own SQL query, how about:

```
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE usr_Table SET description= @description, subject = @subject, text = @text, status = @status WHERE code = @code", connectionString);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("description", newDescription));
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("subject", newSubject));
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("text", newText));
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("status", newStatus));
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("subject", newSubject));
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("code", code));

sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

That'll supply all the named parameters to the query, with the new values.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I think I'm close, but how Do I assign a column in my C# table to one of these SqlParameters? They are dynamically read from the server database so how can I declare them?

Comment: Ah sorry, I see what you're trying to do now - I thought you were trying to update individual rows. Have a look at http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlcommandbuilder - it details how to use a SqlCommandBuilder, which (to quote the page) "helps UPDATE SQL Server tables ... eliminates the need to write the commands". You can acquire the DataTable from the database, make the changes necessary, and then simply `.Update(Table)`, which will create the SQL UPDATE statement(s) for you.

Comment: Also, as I've mentioned already - and apologies if it's not appropriate for your code - this kind of thing is (IMHO) MUCH easier with LINQ. You can read, modify and update the database table directly without having to write any SQL yourself or bringing the data into a DataTable.

Comment: LINQ sounds great, is there any chance you could add an example of how I would use it to your answer please?

Comment: I do most of my work in SQL, hence why I leaned towards it without considering alternatives..

Comment: It really depends on how you use the DataTable in your code, and it might be beyond the scope of what could be shown here. Have a look at http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx - it's slightly out of date but should hopefully give you a start. At the very basic level, add a "Linq to SQL Class" in Visual Studio, and then from "Server Explorer" drag one of the tables into the Designer. You can then read and update the table as a C# class.